# How to retrieve the value within objects to display in a loop

Tags: c++

So I made this simplified code for a banking system (withdrawal and deposit) with two bank accounts using objects and several switches. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class bank
{  private :
        int accnum;
        float currentbal;
        float wallet;
        float amount;
        
    public :
        bank(float bal) : currentbal(bal)
        {
            
        }
        void deposit()
        {   cout << "\nHow much would to deposit:";
            cin >> amount;
            if (wallet<amount){
                cout << "\nInsufficient funds\n";
            } else {
                currentbal = currentbal + amount;
                cout << "new balance is $ " << currentbal << "\n";
                wallet = wallet - amount; }
        }
        void withdraw()
        {   cout << "\ncurrent balance $ " << currentbal;
            cout << "\nHow much would to withdraw: ";
            cin >> amount;
            if (amount>currentbal){
                cout << "\nInsufficient funds\n";
            } else {
                currentbal = currentbal - amount;
                cout << "new balance is $ " << currentbal << "\n";
                wallet = wallet + amount; }
        }
        void menu()
        {   cout << "\n1 to withdraw";
            cout << "\n2 to deposit";  }
};
main()
{   int input;
    int input2;
    int input3;
    float wallet;
    
    bank b1(1000);
    bank b2(2000);
    
    do {
    cout << "\nCurrent wallet: $ " << wallet << "\n";
    cout << "\nSelect bank account:\n";
    cout << "Select 1 for alpha";
    cout << "\nSelect 2 for beta";
    cout << "\nSelect 3 to exit\n";
    cout << "Input: ";
    cin >> input;
    switch (input) {
        case 1 :
            {   b1.menu();
                cout << "\nInput: ";
                cin >> input2;
                switch (input2) {
                    case 1 :
                        b1.withdraw();
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                        b1.deposit();
                        break;
                    default :
                        cout << "\nivalid input.\n";
                    }
                break;
             }  
        case 2 :
            {   b2.menu();
                cout << "\nInput: ";
                cin >> input3;
                switch (input3) {
                    case 1 :
                        b2.withdraw();
                        break;
                    case 2 :
                        b2.deposit();
                        break;
                    default :
                        cout << "\nivalid input.\n";
                    }
                break;
             }
        case 3 :
            cout << "\nThank you";
            break;
        default :
            cout << "\nPlease enter valid input.\n";
     }
    
    } while (input != 3);
}
```

I have everything working correctly but here is my problem, I cannot seem to figure out how to properly display the amount for the variable *wallet* in the loop. It only stays at value 0 and I think my main problem is trying to extract the calculated value from the functions of the objects and display it within the loop. How do I exactly retrieve the value for *wallet* and have it displayed and updated on loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should write a *getter* function for your class

```
class bank
{
    ...
    float get_wallet() const { return wallet; }
    ...
};
```

then something like

```
b1.deposit();
std::cout << b1.get_wallet();
```

Getter functions are the standard way to get at the values of variables inside objects. You do not need the `wallet` variable in `main` (which has no connection with the `wallet` variable inside `bank`).